# Test communication to backend in Angular

Tags: angular, integration-testing, karma-jasmine, backend

I want to test the communication between front-end and backend in Angular. I to isolate the tests from the Gui and test only the service (e.g. FileService), communicating with the backend. This means I do not want to make e2e tests, but I would prefer a unit test framework.

The problem is that I have two backends (local and cloud), for each I have a separate proxy-config file and a configuration file.

My idea was to call something like `ng test --proxy-config proxy.conf.local.json`. But Karma does not support proxy-config. As I read here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9979 Angular team does not plan to add this functionality.

Does any alternative to e2e tests exist in my case?

Comment: You can use Jest test https://jestjs.io/

Comment: Do you have an example, how can I use the same proxy-config file for jest and for the Angular? I have tried to find something in Jest documentation but without luck.